# Is $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta(x-x_0)f(x) \, dx = f(x_0)$ sufficient to define delta distributions?

Tags: definite-integrals, definition, dirac-delta

Most of the sources start introductory section of the delta distributions by 
defining 
\begin{eqnarray}
\delta(x-x_0)&=&\begin{cases}
    \infty, & \text{if $x=x_0$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases} \\
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta(x-x_0) \, dx &=& 1
\end{eqnarray}

then the statement follows that,
\begin{eqnarray}
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta(x-x_0)f(x) \, dx &=&\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left(\int^{x_0-\epsilon}_{-\infty}\delta(x-x_0)f(x) \, dx + \int^{x_0+ \epsilon}_{x_0-\epsilon}\delta(x-x_0)f(x) \, dx \\+ \int^{\infty}_{x_0+\epsilon}\delta(x-x_0)f(x) \, dx \right) \\
&=& f(x_0)\int^{x_0+ \epsilon}_{x_0-\epsilon}\delta(x-x_0)f(x) \, dx \\
&=& f(x)
\end{eqnarray}

Why not define last equation to define delta distributions and use first and second statements as corollaries?

Comment: What are "most sources"? For example, [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) gives the last equation before the equation $\delta(x-a)=0$ for $x\neq a$ and doesn't say what $\delta(0)$ is.

Comment: The last equation is the usual definition I've seen, except with the added caveat that $f$ should be continuous in a neighborhood of zero for this to make sense.

Comment: @David K: Most (read: physics/engineering) sources define the delta function using this nonsense.

Comment: @AlexR. That's the distinction I was trying to imply. My first encounter with the Dirac delta was in physics; I don't recall exactly how it was defined, but it was aggressively hand-wavy: paraphrasing broadly, "We let the mathematicians worry about those technicalities; the important thing is, we know it works."

Comment: The first two are usually used to define the $\delta$ *function*, in my somewhat limited experience.

Answer (score 0):

references:

a) "Mathematics for the Physical Sciences", Laurent Schwartz;

b) "Generalized Functions vol 1", I.M. Gelfand, G. E. Shilov.

These are classics and primary sources in the areas of generalized functions, b), and distributions, a).  I think generalized functions and distributions are the same thing, see wiki 'generalized functions'.

However $δ(x-a)$ is commonly defined by

1) $$f(a)=\int f(x)δ(x-a)dx ,$$

Where f, a 'test function', is adequately well behaved.  So δ(.) is usually defined by its action under the integral sign. Sometimes, in addition, its value is given as zero everywhere except at the single point, a, where its value is infinity, but this may not be needed.

However there are problems with this definition since a value at a single point should not change the value of an integral. So instead sometimes a 'inner product' (or 'scalar product'--not sure about the terminology) is used

2) $f(0) = (f(x) , δ(x)) $, Gelfand p4

or

3) $f(0) = <f(x) , δ(x)> $, Schwartz p77.

From these $f(a) = (f(x) , δ(x-a)) $ follows.

So my answer is 2) or 3) are more proper basic definitions than 1), and are all that is needed.